# ssh to server and have to get the count of given strings in server

Tags: unix, ssh

I have unix script in server1 that ssh to another server2 and grep and count the some strings in a file and has to return the count to different files(of different string count in server2) in server1.

`ssh username@server2`

`grep 'string1' file1 | wc -l >> file2 (in server1 )`

`grep 'string2' file1 | wc -l >> file3 (in server1 )`

`grep 'string3' file1 | wc -l >> file4 (in server1 )`

as I already in server2, script is returning as file2,file3 and file4 not found

but I am able to do like below:

`ssh username@server2 grep 'string1' file1 | wc -l >> file2 (in server1 )`

`ssh username@server2 grep 'string2' file1 | wc -l >> file3 (in server1 )`

`ssh username@server2 grep 'string3' file1 | wc -l >> file4 (in server1 )`

but i have to connect to server2 only once and i have to get the count in file2,file3 and file 4.

Is there any other way so that I can connect only once server2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shh`executes a command on a remote server. The output goes back to server1.

In your case the command would be `grep 'string1' file1`. The output processing is done on server1, thus the file1 is located on server1.

With only one login you may combine the commands (quoting to tell ssh that the whole string is to be executed remote)

```
ssh username@server2 "grep ... | wc -l; grep...; grep ..."` >> server1.log
```

Then the output of all commands goes back to server1 and into the file. And it is up to you to split it up.

If you just quote the `"grep 'string1' file1 | wc -l"` the counting should be done on the server2 and only the result is sent back. The repeated login **may** be not a problem any more. ( I assume big result sets from grep to be moved over the network)

Comment: Thanks a lot  ULick. repeated login taking more time(239 sec)but the code u have given took 6 sec. Thank you once again